# PHP Extract zip string

Tags: php, zip, zlib

I have an integration project with ERP system that return me a list of invoices compressed with zip as binary string:

> Xc1NCsIwEEDhq0j2ZuIPCEWF4qqgNNCN2yFWGzAzMhmMvb1g0YUHeN/b1iI4tlcvkSXq2NCTY+hnr3SnvDOD6qMCyGHoE2Z7QcXApIJBLcsNls6twW1gyn3b1b6xB06Jyf6R2UxoFX9sKcWW1RdawPl07D6neaSsSKE3sH8D

I can't success to extract it, I try with `gzuncompress()`, `new ArchiverZip()` also try to convert it from `bin2hex`, `base64` ... and nothing, I should get an object from this string.

The guys which develop the ERP system, told me that they are compress it with Ionic (??):
`Ionic.Zlib.DeflateStream.UncompressBuffer(compressedData);`

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Format the code, my eyes will thank you!

Comment: Have you tried gzdecode? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php

Comment: So... have you tried using Ionic to decompress it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is compressed with raw deflate (no zlib, gzip, or zip wrapper around the deflate data), and base64 encoded.  Decoded and decompressed, it's:

```
<ArrayOfPriorityInvoice xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PrioriPOSAPI.Common.PriorityInvoices" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Use `base64_decode()` and `gzinflate()` to extract the data.

Comment: Thanks mark, can you post the code? cause I'm getting warning

Comment: Ok got it. thank you! BTW it's amazing getting an answer from u :)

Comment: gzinflate - To decode / uncompress the received HTTP POST data in PHP code, request data coming from Java / Android application via HTTP POST GZIP / DEFLATE compressed format

Answer (score -1):

Try to read the string using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

Then write a zip file into a tmp folder, then extract it

Tell me if you need further explaination